# QR Codes not displaying in emails, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I'm dealing with a legacy Rails website. I am trying to put QR codes in an email (which otherwise works normally on the website), uses QRCode.js.

```
<% @tires.each do |tire| %>
  <h3>TIRE <%= tire.id %> QR CODE</h3>
  <div class="barcode-main" id="barcode_<%=tire.id%>"></div>
  <script> 
    var qrcode = new QRCode("barcode_<%=tire.id%>", {
    text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
  </script>
<% end %> etc
```

In Gmail inspection the element is:

```
<div id="m_142369116572343918barcode_49"></div>
```

In Outlook inspection the element is:

```
<div id="x_barcode_49"></div>
```

No class, and the id is altered with gibberish in front of it. Works normally as an attachment and everywhere else.

... I have also now tried the same with RQRCode and Google Chart QR - can get them to show on the website, but not in an email. With RQRCode the elements show up as `<u></u>` and with Google Chart QR it is a broken image.

Comment: And the `class` attribute is not present either?

Comment: Could there be some JavaScript involved that could be rewriting that `<div>` or replacing it?

Comment: What mu said. If you're sure server generates html with `barcode_49` then there has to be some javascript changing it. You can confirm that by disabling JS in the browser and inspecting the DOM or using curl or similar.

Comment: yes no class either. Actually my bad, the resulting html is is in an email which i'm viewing through gmail, i'll update the question. will also look for javascript, thank you

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's something you should have mentioned upfront. It makes a big difference if it's email or regular page.

Comment: Confirmed, is an email thing, thank you. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed with 3 QR gems, and eventually got it with QuickChart (didn't realize Google Charts QR was depreciated).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).